# ResolveUrl can't find webservice in folder

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a web application with a webform page (`WebForm5.aspx`). In `WebForm5.aspx` I use some script to get data from a WebService (`LookUpLocation.asmx`)

[image: Root]

Here is the script that I am using:
[image]

If I run the application the way it is setup now with the WebForm5.aspx and the WebService (LookUpLocation.asmx) in the root directory, the application and the script runs just like it is supposed to.

The problem I am having is that I would like to put my WebForm5.aspx in the 'Forms' folder and the Web Service (LookUpLocation.asmx) in the 'WebService' folder that are in the root directory.

But when I do that I get an error when I try to load the application:

[image]

I use 
url: `<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebServices/LookUpLocation.asmx/GetLocationsByPrefix")%>`,

as the code in the script for the path to get to the web service folder.

I have tried many variations for the path for the ResolveUrl with NO luck.

What am I doing wrong. Very Frustrating.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since you are using jquery on your WebForm5.aspx, please ensure that jquery script reference has correct path. Error `$ is undefined` indicates that jquery library is failing to load

Comment: Yes that is the first thing I checked and it is loading the jquery  library. Thanks

Comment: What is line 60 in your code?

Comment: Line 60 is the first line of the script:

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: and the column 9 is the '$'

Comment: Have you checked if there are multiple jquery references causing conflicts? Also, try using `jQuery` instead of `$` on first script line i.e `jQuery(document).ready` to see if that moves the error to next line.